# How to inject dbcontext with StructureMap and WebApi2

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, structuremap, dbcontext

I would like to inject my dbcontext into my services in web api 2 project.  But I’m a little unsure of how to do that.  I've read through the docs but lifecycles, scopes, requests, nested containers...they all leave me a little unsure.  I have pieced together the following code from my best understanding.  After installing the Nuget package StructureMap.WebApi2, I proceeded to update SM from v3 to v4, as well as the SM.MVC5 from v3 to v4.

The following code appears to have the desired effect of using one dbcontext per http request (I think that's what i want...i'm so confused about scopes) so that the same dbcontext is shared for all services during a users transaction, and then disposed when the transaction (http request) is closed. But appearances are not always right.

IoC.cs

```
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container(_ =>
        {
            _.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>();
            _.ForConcreteType<MyDbContext>().Configure.ContainerScoped();
        });
        DomainEvents.Initialize(container);
        return container;
    }}
```

DefaultRegistry.cs:

```
    public DefaultRegistry()
    {
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new Common.Map.MapProfile());
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        });
        var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        For<IMapper>().Use(() => mapperConfig.CreateMapper());
        For<MyDbContext>().Use(()=> new MyDbContext());

        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<ServiceBase>();
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));
            });
    }
```

The Nuget package StructureMap.WebApi2 created some other files for wiring up resolution and nested containers, but i'm leaving them out of this question for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Mehdime DbContext Scope Factory / Locator: https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope and he has a bit of a run-down of it on his blog. (link in the project description.) There are forks off there updated to the latest EF versions.

I've found it to be an excellent unit of work wrapper for EF contexts without having to worry about injecting or passing around those contexts directly.

The trouble with IoC containers and constructor injection is that if you register your DBContext it means that it's hard to work with things like a unit of work within the scope of a request without it essentially being the entire scope of the request. The DbContext Scope solves this by having you register a Scope Factory and a Scope Locator in your Container. Code controlling the Scope (unit of work) will use the Scope Factory to initialize a context scope for your DbContexts.   Code operating with DbSets etc. in a DbContext use the ContextScopeLocator to get their UoW /w it's DbContext & sets.

Comment: I've glanced at that before, but will take another look.  My first reaction, however, is that since i'm in a web environment, the majority of my uses will be as a single uow per request.  So far i have not found a need to scope a second dbcontext within the same request.  This may be a good alternative suggestion that i eventually adopt, but unfortunately it fails to answer my question about whether or not my code above is correct.